# How to fix the error 'OverwriteModelError: Cannot overwrite `Stats` model once compiled.'?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, discord.js

I'm stuck with the error `OverwriteModelError: Cannot overwrite 'Stats' model once compiled`.

First of all my `character.js` code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const Stats = require("../models/stats.js");
const Character = require("../models/characters.js");
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/AdvendowDatabase', {
  useNewUrlParser: true
});

exports.run = (client, message, args) => {
  if (args[0] === 'help' || args[0] === 'list') {
    let helpEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
      .setAuthor('Character List')
      .setDescription(`All available Characters:\n\nMia - Assassin: 6A, 2D, 100HP\n\nSelect a character with \`<char select charname\``)
      .setFooter(`A = Attack, D = Defence, HP = Health/Hitpoints`);
    message.channel.send(helpEmbed);
  }
  if (args[0] === 'select') {
    let selection = args[1].toLowerCase();
    if (selection) return message.channel.send("Please define a character! <char select >CHARNAME<");
    Stats.findOne({
      userID: message.author.id
    }, (err, charchecker) => {
      if (charchecker) return message.channel.send(`Sorry you already have selected ${charchecker.character}`);
      Character.findOne({
        name: selection
      }, (err, character) => {
        if (!character) return message.channel.send(`There is no character with the name ${selection}! run <char list to see all available characters!`);
        let att = character.attack + 0;
        let def = character.defence + 0;
        let char = character.name;
        let clas = character.class;
        let hp = character.health + 0;
        Stats.findOne({
          userID: message.author.id
        }, (err, stats) => {
          const newChar = new Stats({
            userID: message.author.id,
            character: char,
            class: clas,
            level: 1,
            exp: 0,
            money: 0,
            attack: att,
            defence: def,
            health: hp
          });
          console.log(`[Advendow] ${message.author.username}: registered`);
          newChar.save().catch(err => console.log(err));
          message.channel.send(`[ACCOUNT CREATED]: Your registraiton was succesfull!\nYour Char: ${char} | ${clas}`);
        });
      });
    });
  }
}

exports.help = {
  name: "character",
  name2: "char"
}
```

`Stats.js` model script:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const statsShema = mongoose.Schema({
  userID: String,
  character: String,
  class: String,
  money: Number,
  level: Number,
  exp: Number,
  attack: Number,
  defence: Number,
  health: Number,

}, {
  collection: 'stats'
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Stats', statsShema);
```

Comment: Why is this all in `exports.run`? Where is the actual code calling that export and invoking that function? Seems to me that your mongoose connection and models really should be "required" and connected elsewhere, and not within this function. Database connections are meant to persist for the life-cycle of your application.

Comment: Well, I have already fixed it.